# So im looking to locate the indexPath.row of cell that has just been edited, aka inside of func textViewDidEndEditing

Tags: swift, tableview

Update: alright so I've tried to use the code as suggested in the duplicate question and does not seem to work for me, as Ive made clear previously I want to access the indexPath.row outside of the cellForRowAt function, but CANT access it through the custom cell, as I need the UITextView delegate in the tableViewController in order to update tableView on textViewDidChange in order to have the automatic resizing of cells to work.

ive tried to write this code and I've written notes as to what happens at each individual spot when I check it with console. ill post the code beneath.

as previously mentioned I want to save the text from user input, and erasing it once indexPath.row = row of text input.

```
 //if endEditing, save text to array cellNumber, at the point inside the array, equalavant of the indexPath.row
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView){

    //get position of current row
    var position: CGPoint = self.tableView.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView) // always returns 0.0 0.0 pos

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: position){ //returns 0, 0 always 

        let cellIndexPathRow = indexPath.row // problem: always comes back as 0, should return indexPath.row
        print(cellIndexPathRow)
        cellNumber.insert(textView.text, at: cellIndexPathRow)}

}
```

Comment: Do you want to change item's text property based on which TextField did end editing?

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, ignore the accepted answer and look at the answers with more upvotes. Replace references to the button with your text view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the cell like this

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView){
    if let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells as? [CustomCellClass], let cell = cells.filter({$0.textView == textView}).first {
        // Do what you want with the cell here
    }
}
```

Comment: Now he can change cell's outlets/properties but its data won't be saved in data souce array.

Comment: yeah and if you've read the code, it already did save the data to an array. my problem was, and is, that I need to know what the indexPath.row is, so that I can save it to the appropriate point in the array.